# New Doc Library Experience - attach Metadata to folders

Tags: document-library, metadata

Does the new Doc Library Experience allow for attaching metadata to folders? I can only get it to attach metadata to documents.

**Here is the "old/classic" view where I've attached a Description and Choice column to a folder.**

[image]

**Here is the New Experience view showing a Description Column on a document:**

[image]

**Here is the New Experience View for a folder - but the "Description" column never appears in the area for me to edit.**

[image]

The reason I specifically want to attach a description column to this folder is that the folder has elevated permissions and is not viewable to everyone in the department. Because SP hides folders from people that don't have access - I am going to have a "training issue" as years go by. My users are going to forget that the folder has elevated permissions and they are not going to remember that only certain people can access the folder - hence the need to put that information in front of their noses in the folder's metadata. I can accomplish this in the classic view. If it cannot be done in the New Experience, it's going to cause major problems for me and my organization. Any advice? Thanks ahead of time!

Matt D.